# pg_ctl : не удалось запустить сервер

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Установил postgresql,после установки никакие конфигурационные файлы не редактировал.
Но при запуске pg_ctl возникает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В протоколе выполнения:

> 2023-05-31 12:07:22.289 +04 [6836] —ќќЅў≈Ќ»≈:  запускаетс¤ PostgreSQL 14.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
> 2023-05-31 12:07:22.293 +04 [6836] —ќќЅў≈Ќ»≈:  не удалось прив¤затьс¤ к адресу IPv6 "::1": Permission denied
> 2023-05-31 12:07:22.293 +04 [6836] —ќќЅў≈Ќ»≈:  не удалось прив¤затьс¤ к адресу IPv4 "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
> 2023-05-31 12:07:22.293 +04 [6836] ѕ–≈ƒ”ѕ–≈∆ƒ≈Ќ»≈:  не удалось создать принимающий сокет дл¤ "localhost"
> 2023-05-31 12:07:22.293 +04 [6836] ¬ј∆Ќќ:  не удалось создать сокеты TCP/IP
> 2023-05-31 12:07:22.295 +04 [6836] —ќќЅў≈Ќ»≈:  система Ѕƒ выключена

Пробовал установить версию 15.3, аналогичное поведение...

Comment: Удалось разобраться. Порт 5432 уже использовался.
Нашел пид процесса который его занял и убил - netstat -aon | findstr 5432
Странно, ведь перед повторной установкой PG, старую версию я полностью сносил..